# Weight and Mass of biggest human hand

Tags: geometry

I was recently wondering what the weight of the biggest human hand on record would have been, it's only really known how long it was. Robert Wadlow, also known as the tallest man ever had hands 32.3 cm (12.75 in) long. Using that starting point could someone please figure out the necessary things to reach an approximate weight and mass, to make it simpler maybe use the formula for a sphere to help reach your conclusion to represent a fist?

Bonus if you can tell me the initial number but then applying a double that amount or any times number higher to account for bone in some regard.

Answer in kilograms and pounds please.

Thank you for the help!

Comment: If there was a biology SE, I would recommend moving this question there.

Answer (score 1):

I would measure the length and volume of your own hand.  There are two ways to get the volume.  One is to make a fist as you say and try to approximate the volume by breaking it into approximate cylinders.  Another is to immerse it in water and measure the displaced volume.  The second will be more accurate if you can find an appropriately calibrated vessel.  Once you have the length and volume of your hand, the volume scales as the cube of the length ratios, so if your hand were $10$ inches long his hand would have a volume $1.275^3$ times larger.  Finally use the fact that people have about the same density as water to get the mass.  We are making the assumption that the largest hand is a scaled up version of yours, which may not be very accurate, but I don't see how to do better.